# Add Custom attributes Wordpress nav item

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to add custom attributes to **single** WordPress menu item.

```
<li id="menu-item-365" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-children-0">
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/whats-new/">WHATS NEW</a>
</li>
```

But I need this code like this

```
<li id="menu-item-365" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-children-0">
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/whats-new/" data-reveal-id="myModal1" data-animation="fade">WHATS NEW</a>
</li>
```

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 7):

Filter this, targetting a specific menu id is fairly easy:

Add the following to your `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'my_nav_menu_attribs', 10, 3 );
function my_nav_menu_attribs( $atts, $item, $args )
{
  // The ID of the target menu item
  $menu_target = 365;

  // inspect $item
  if ($item->ID == $menu_target) {
    $atts['data-reveal-id'] = 'myModal1';
    $atts['data-animation'] = 'fade';
  }
  return $atts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but no luck!

Comment: Hello, this works for me :) Are you calling your menu with wp_nav_menu ?

Comment: Just to confirm, i've got this working on my localhost, can you comment on how you've implemented your menu and the above code?

Comment: No, theme is **not** using wp-nav-menu in header.php  
Is there anyway I can do this with PHP? jQuery wasn't a good solution

Comment: How is it implemented? I would implement `wp_nav_menu` and target your main menu. The above code is filtering and making use of it. `http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu`. Good luck, your theme sounds a bit strange :)

Comment: I found `wp_nav_menu` in `theme\templates\header\main-navigation.php`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

Comment: Can you explain this little bit?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about Walker_Nav_Menu concept in WordPress?

here is an example, http://www.wpexplorer.com/adding-custom-attributes-to-wordpress-menus/

Comment: I don't need to add these attributes to every menu item on the nav

Answer (score 0):

**For WordPress functions.php**

If you need to add attributes to more than one menu item:

```
function add_specific_menu_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {

$menu_items = array(66,72);

if (in_array($item->ID, $menu_items)) {
   $atts['data-ps2id-offset'] = '-75';
}

return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_specific_menu_atts', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#menu-item-365').find('a').attr('data-reveal-id', 'myModal1');
        $('#menu-item-365').find('a').attr('data-animation', 'fade');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now it's working but other things which use jQuery, aren't working properly.. Can you help please? Site using jQuery v1.10.2

Comment: No problem for updating wordpress.

Comment: JS isn't really the best solution

Comment: I think the idea is to use WordPress internal API instead of adding a new tool, otherwise, it will be in jQuery or javascript category.